# Reading JSON to object: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, java-8

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
field1: "asd",
theBigField: "bigggg300mb",
field2: "tyu"
}
```

What I have on the method input parameter is InputStream. I can't increase memory on JVM so that it would accept the message. I also can't do `return new ObjectMapper().readValue(bytes, MyModel.class)` as I don't have so much memory to create object from this message. What I would like to do is to extract field1 and field2 from the message and validate them against some rules.

And I have InputStream on the method start.. From it I got byte array.. How could I extract `field1` and `field2` ?

I am using Java8, I can use popular opensource and light libraries. Maybe it could be done in some other way, programatically ?

What I want to avoid is not to read the whole message into memory, so it should be some kind of iterating approach.

Comment: `Spring MVC` provides this functionality out of the box.

Comment: I dont have Spring MVC it is Camel routing and InputStream is in message body. I have to extract parameters and validate them.

Comment: Check out the GSON streaming documentation: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming "This code reads a JSON document containing an array of messages. It steps through array elements as a stream to avoid loading the complete document into memory."

Comment: @michealAtmi I only mention Spring because you posted "I can use popular opensource and light libraries". Spring is both popular and opensource. Maybe not so light, but two out of three...

Comment: Kind of an overkill, but you could use JFlex to parse your JSON file: http://www.jflex.de/ Use an existing JSON definition file and tweak it to retrieve yours fields.

Comment: It seems to work withgson :).. However I need one more thing. Just to check wheter the bigField is not empty (such validation). I don't wan't to read it whole to memory, maybe u have some ideeas ?

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt would be annotating `MyClass::theBigField` with `@JsonIgnore` (if you use Jackson/ObjectMapper). Not sure if it'll work, though.

As a last resort, if the input structure is fixed and you know it beforehand, you can try to parse the stream manually. Something like this:

```java
    private static void parseMyJson(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
          StringBuffer[] fields = new StringBuffer[] { new StringBuffer(), null, new StringBuffer() };
          int fieldNum = 0;
          boolean readingFieldValue = false;
          int read = 0;
          while ((read = stream.read()) != -1) {
            char readChar = (char) read;
            if (readChar == '"') {
               fieldNum += readingFieldValue ? 0 : 1;
               readingFieldValue = !readingFieldValue;
            } else if (readingFieldValue && fieldNum != 2) {
               fields[fieldNum-1].append(readChar);
            }
          }
          System.out.println(fields[0].toString());
          System.out.println(fields[2].toString());
    }
```

The code above is a very primitive and inefficient parser (you probably will need something more advanced) but the point is that you only allocate in memory a chunk of read characters and then discard them if they do not correspond to the fields you are interested in.

Comment: thanks, nice but since gson has that feature, I am trying to use gson